# get selected item from dropdownlist in gridview using jquery on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview in which i have added dropdown list and button .On Rowdatabound event i am filling dropdown list
On Button  click i want to check selected item in drop down list at clientside at the same row how i can do this.i was able to add script for confirm message on button like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function confirmpo() {
            if (confirm("Genrate order for this product?")) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>

<asp:GridView ID="grdColorname" runat="server" onrowcommand="grdvendorname_RowCommand" >

<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" HeaderText="Company Id" Visible="false"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Productname" HeaderText="Product name" />
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" >
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="lstvendor" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:DropDownList>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button ID="btnGenratepo" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' CssClass="btnclassedit" runat="server" CommandName="GenratePO" Text="" ToolTip="Genrate P/O" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmpo();"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField
</Columns>
<RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />

    <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />

    <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />

    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />

    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />

    <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />

    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" /> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Any Suggestion on how to do this.

Comment: you will have to understand the structure of gridview control. It render in a table format. You can use pre(), next() and prarent(). child() method of jQuery to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, inside `confirmpo()`, you want to see the value of the `<select>` on the same row as the button?

In that case, first you need to look at the rendered HTML of the page. The gridview will be rendered as a table. You can use the event that is passed to `confirmpo()` like this:

```
function confirmpo(e) {
    var btn = e.srcElement;
    // .. locate the <select> element
    // .. insert rest of the code
}
```

You should probably go via the `parentNode` properties up to the `<tr>`, and then get to the `<select>`. All of this can be done easier with a DOM traversal library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It will look like this not tested

```
$("#grdColorname input:button").click(function(){
 var selectedValue=$(this).parent('td').prev('td').find('input:select').value();
});
```

the selectedValue will contain your required value for your drop-down list.